# ESRI-Leaflet updateFeature with a changed attribute or property

Tags: leaflet, feature-layer, feature-service, esri-leaflet

I'm updating a feature in ESR-Leaflet from a feature layer based on a call to a function. What I'm having trouble with is submitting this change to the feature service.

Currently I:
Get the feature based on it's ObjectID;
Reach into the feature.properties and change "SystemStatus";
Attempt to submit updateFeatures (and fail).

Code, and error below.

```
function ChangeStatus(objID){
    var retireFeatureID = hotspots.getFeature(objID);
    retireFeatureID.feature.properties["SystemStatus"] = "Deleted";
    hotspots.updateFeature(retireFeatureID, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             return;
        }   
            console.log(response);
    });
    //hotspots.updateFeature(retireFeatureID);
    console.log("Updated the status of feature: " + objID);
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> {code: 400, message: "Cannot perform operation. Invalid operation
>   parameters.", details: Array(2)} code: 400 details: (2) ["'features'
>   parameter is invalid", "Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."] message: "Cannot perform operation. Invalid operation
>   parameters."

I'm not sure what could be causing my issue here. 
Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the updateFeature line. I needed to include '.feature' because otherwise it was sending the entire object, which is not what was expected.

```
function WriteLog(objID){
    var retireFeatureID = hotspots.getFeature(objID);
    retireFeatureID.feature.properties["SystemStatus"] = "Deleted";
    hotspots.updateFeature(retireFeatureID.feature, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return "error";
        }   
            console.log(response);
            return "ok";
    });
    console.log("Updated the status of feature: " + objID);
}
```